# am i applying the property correctly??

Tags: laplace-transform

The time shifting property states that:

$$  \mathcal{L}(u(t-t_0)f(t-t_0))=e^{-st_0}F(s)        $$

Now I am given a question which is:

$$ \mathcal{L}(e^{-4t}u(t-3))    $$

Can I do like I have done here? That the time shift is of 3 seconds, so using the property I get final answer as:

$$        \frac{e^{-3s}}{s+4}      $$

Edit: if we are asked to find unilateral Laplace Transform then and only then do I get the above answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrong!
Go step by step.

Step $1$: Find frequency shift due to $e^{-4t}$ using:

If $\mathcal{L}(f(t))=F(s)$, then
$\mathcal{L}(e^{-4t}f(t))=F(s+4)$. (which is the answer)

Step $2$: Find $\mathcal{L}(f(t))$ by the property of time shift as follows:
$$\mathcal{L}(u(t-3).1)=\frac{e^{-3s}}{s}$$
where $f(t)=u(t-3).1$

So that finally $$F(s+4)=\frac{e^{-3(s+4)}}{s+4}$$

Comment: can you tell me why can't apply the property over here? what are the cases where we can apply this property? does those cases involve the unshifted version of unit step functions?